# Attracting Candidates from the same Company

Tags: job-offer

A couple of years ago, I was approached by this insurance company to work for the IS department.

I had to relocate to work for them.

I was kind of curious, why would they bring all the way to this new city while they are already located in the city where employees are highly available.

Two weeks after my incorporation, I discovered that my boss was so obnoxious and that no one wants to collaborates with her.

I spent the next six months in hell (kept saying that she would terminate my contract), and brought her to a confrontation that involved HR, which exacerbated her reputation.

In the mean time, she couldn't find a good reason to fire me, everyone admitted that I was skilled.

I dazzingly achieved a project which I think she assigned to me to fail and give a good reason to fire me.

I managed to go back to the initial company where I was happily working, and many colleagues would tell me that this horrible insurance company is contacting them.

Why would this insurance company try to attract people from the same company, that is 5 hours away, after a catastrophic experience with an employee who trusted them and relocated?

Are they just looking for some naive employee who might not have heard of the bad reputation of that manager?

Comment: Hi Leonidas. That sounds like a horrible situation, but all we can do is speculate about the company's motives sorry, and that won't be helpful to anyone. I suggest you be happy you've got out, and don't look back. Don't waste any more time thinking about them at all.

Comment: Back in the 1990's, a telecom company in the USA, which had a logo that resembled the death star would recruit from literally any company that they could because they couldn't retain people.  They also had to raise their offers to 150% of the industry standard just to get people in the door.  This may be similar

Answer (score 5):

At plenty of companies, the people doing the recruiting are extremely disconnected from those working in various departments. A good friend of mine worked in HR and the way that hiring operated was a manager filled in a form when they needed someone, it was approved by some executive and then was sent to them to be filled.

So at his company, the recruiters would have had no idea about the problem manager, the catastrophic experience, or why you left. They would just have been told to fill another job for X dollars with Y skills.

You are vastly overestimating information sharing in companies.

I would bet that the people doing the recruiting have no idea why you left. They do know that people at your company are receptive to moving. That is probably why they are coming for employees at your firm again.

Even if they do know the manager is a problem, they are still required to try and fill the job and making it seem like they properly tried. Getting a bunch of quick declines from an employer they know staff are willing to leave helps to cover their asses.